# Integrating Google+ in an iOS app

Tags: ios, google-plus, social-networking

In order to get my hands on the Google API for iOS, I ran the GooglePlusSample.xcodeproj sample project provided by Google.
Then I trimmed it, up to the level where only what I am interested in at this point is left over.
Precisely my simplified version can log in and out, nothing else. That works perfectly.

When using "com.google.GooglePlusPlatformSample" for the bundle identifier (this is what is provided in the Google sample).
The app starts and when I tap the "Sign in" cell, I get this:

> Status: Not authenticated

which is what I expect. Then I can log in an get:

> Status: Authenticated

All this is fine.
But when I use "myreversedomain.myapp" for the bundle identifier (this is my own app), adjusting the Product Name accordingly in the Build Settings.
The app starts as previously and when I tap the "Sign in" cell, I get this:

> Status: Not authenticated

which is still what I expect. Then I try to log in. This is the time when things go wrong. Instead of getting

> Status: Authenticated

as before: I find myself using the Google+ app which is installed on my device.

Since I am just starting to use the Google API in an iOS app, I may well be doing something not right. But why is this happening?

Comment: hi, please refer the following link: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started
hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it is not very helpful at this point, because this is exactly where I started. It was useful to begin with. But I am now in front of a new issue as explained in my post.

Comment: you can try by setting the callBack URL for this. This may help you to come back to your application from the GooglePlus app.

Comment: That seems interesting. But I'll have to figure out how to do that.
For now I have no idea. Thanks for your tip anyway.

Comment: For that you have to provide the Redirect url with your register app in the Google Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding Redirect URL you have to provide the Redirect URL in you Register App settings on Google Plus. Refer the following image.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Great! That did it. My settings with Google were right, but I hadn't added the URL Type in the Info part of the app.

Comment: @Michel Im also facing the same problem of Status :Not Authenticated. And I didn't get wht's the solution here.Please tell me where do I need to change the URI in my app and with which URI I need to replace

Comment: My reply may already be late, but just in case. As far as I remember I had  to go to the Info tab of my project settings (URL Types, I think). And you may have to check your settings for your app on Google.